# Play 2.4.x -- what are the most efficient type of Objects to place in a @Twirl template?

Tags: playframework-2.0, twirl

You can place many things inside a @Twirl template and obviously something is concatenating all of those things into a final output String (Html)

My question is are there any specific `Object` types (say something like `StringBuilder`) that are easier for @Twirl to digest (meaning compile or perhaps more explicitly run faster at runtime) compared to `String`s?

Comment: From what I have seen in the source code it appears that `StringBuilder` is the raw engine that does the heavy lifting so I would guess that `StringBuilder` would in fact be the most efficient `Object` to add. Based on the knowledge in some far reaches of memory that `StringBuilder`'s append gracefully without resorting to a `String` intermediate `Object`.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java seems to support the above observation as `System.arraycopy` is used without an intermediate `String` `Object`